# Is there a module to form English sentences?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a user interface (UI) that collects adjectives into a set and forms a sentence, but as you can see, the sentence lacks the word "and" in the right place.

[image]

I want a library that i can shove parts of speech into and it spits out the correct English.

Comment: This site does not allow library requests. It's supposed to be for questions about code you've written, which can be answered with more code, generally.